# mysql, php Insert Zero Problems

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to php and writing what I thought was a simple php page to insert data into a mysql table. The table only holds a date and two integers. The problem is with the integers. The code works fine for numbers 1 - 100 but when I enter a zero ( 0 ) it will not insert the data. I'm sure there is a simple explanation but I can't find it. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php   
error_reporting(0);
require 'db/connect.php';
require 'db/security.php';

if (!empty($_POST)) {
if (isset($_POST['logDate'], $_POST['shiftID'], $_POST['deployed'])) {

    $date       = trim($_POST['logDate']);
    $shiftID    = trim($_POST['shiftID']);
    $deployed   = trim($_POST['deployed']);
    $logDate    = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));

        if (!empty($logDate) && !empty($shiftID) && !empty($deployed))        {

            $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO info 
                                    (logDate, shiftID, deployed) 
                                    VALUES (?,?,?)");

            $insert->bind_param('sii', $logDate, $shiftID, $deployed);

            if ($insert->execute()) {
                header ('location: test1.php');
                die();
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: so, check if value = 0 ( or > 0 ) or have your db accept null/zero value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this statement here,

```
if (!empty($logDate) && !empty($shiftID) && !empty($deployed)){ ...
```

And from the [documentation of `empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php),

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> "" (an empty string) 
> 0 (0 as an integer) 
> 0.0 (0 as a float) 
> "0" (0 as a string) 
> NULL 
> FALSE 
> array() (an empty array) 
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

So instead of `empty()`, use `isset()` function, like this:

```
if (isset($logDate) && isset($shiftID) && isset($deployed)){ ...
```

Comment: That fixed it! Big thanks, I've been racking my brain over this one.

Answer (score 0):

The calls to empty() return FALSE on a 0 so remove this check on the integers, or replace with >== 0